# HTML event which fires after loading, but before page displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, events, layout

I have a web page with some JavaScript which I'm running via the 'onload' event for the `<body>` element. The code looks at certain child elements and adjusts all their heights to match the tallest one. This means that the layout always visually shifts a bit after the page is loaded and displayed.

It's fine as it is, but I'm wondering if there's a better event to hook into instead of 'onload' - perhaps one that fires after the page has loaded (so I can access and modify the element heights) but before it is rendered?

Comment: I'm not sure it would help. The element has to render to know what its height should be

Comment: Most likely you can achieve what you need with CSS, no need for JS. Take a look at [CSS positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning), there you should find all you need.

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be a bit paradoxical! I would try and CSS it but I'm dealing with a huge blog theme/template that I didn't create, and for such a small change I'm happy just hooking in and adjusting things with a bit of self contained JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
            console.log('loading')
        }
        if (document.readyState == 'interactive') {
            console.log('interactive')
        }
        if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
            console.log('complete')
        }
        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
            if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
                console.log('visible')
            }
        });
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
         console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
        });
        document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
            if (event.target.readyState === 'interactive') {
                console.log('interactive')
            } else if (event.target.readyState === 'complete') {
                console.log('complete')
            }
        });
```

you can try any of the states that fits your need also links for more examples

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event